# Is there a way to see hidden content

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Look at this code:

```
<div hidden=«@(success==false)»>
A very secret message !
</div>
...
@code {
  ...
  if (password_input==...) success=true;
  ...
  }
```

I Want to know if an hacker who don’t type good password can see secret message.

Thanks

Comment: YES! Don't do anything secret on the client at all. EVER

Comment: Is there a way to force the div not been sent to browser ?

Comment: Don't put it in the markup.

Comment: So, in this case I think you are asking about hiding things until logged in/authorised? use the AuthoriseView component https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if an hacker who don’t type good password can see secret message.

Yes. Learn to use F12 in the Browser and then Elements, Inspect.

But since you're using Blazor server-side, the following is reasonably safe:

```cs
@if(success)
{
   <div >
     A very secret message !
   </div>
}
...
@code {
  ...
  if (password_input==...) success=true;
  ...
  }
```

With Blazor Server the secret message will not be sent to the Client before the password is correct.

With Blazor WebAssembly this would not be safe, just a little harder to crack than `hidden`.